# Duplicate Inserted Row into the new table when running trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, insert

I create 2 tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE task
(
 task_name TEXT NOT NULL,
 duration INT,
 UNIQUE(task_name)
);
CREATE TABLE temptable
(
 task_name TEXT NOT NULL,
 duration INT  NULL,

);
```

Then I insert one row in 'task' table.

```
INSERT INTO public.task(
    task_name, duration)
    VALUES ('task1', 10);
```

I want to insert a new same row into temptable table every time I add new record into task table
So I create a trigger to insert automatically data in 'temptale' at the same time

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_temptable()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    -- insert temporary row
    INSERT INTO temptable(task_name, duration)
    SELECT NEW.task_name , NEW.duration FROM task;
   RETURN NEW;       
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
/* Create trigger call function*/
CREATE TRIGGER ins_new_record
    AFTER INSERT ON task
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_temptable();
```

But when I insert a new row ('task 2',10) into 'task' table, the records inserted into 'temptable' table always duplicated like this.

```
task_name|duration|
|"task2" |10      |
-------------------

|"task2" |10      |
```

I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to prevent a second row in `temptable` with the same `task_name`?

Comment: Yes.I want to insert just the same row(from" task "table)  into "temptable" table.Example: if insert  a row [a] into task table, it also insert row just 1 row [a ]into "temptable" table.

Comment: Then your trigger is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: You probably want `INSERT INTO temptable(task_name, duration) VALUES ( NEW.task_name , NEW.duration)` instead of `INSERT INTO temptable(task_name, duration)
    SELECT NEW.task_name , NEW.duration FROM task`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, I just want insert only one row. But I write wrong code. so I need the help.

Comment: @mustaccio. This is just a simple case, the query is very complex I have many field with conditions, so I convert into simple query like this :)

Comment: @mustaccio: I updated my code. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in your trigger:

```
INSERT INTO temptable
   (task_name, duration)
SELECT NEW.task_name , NEW.duration
FROM task;
```

will insert as many rows into `temptable` as there are currently in `task`. The `SELECT` returns one result row for each row in `task`, and since the `SELECT` list contains only constants, all these result rows will look the same.

You want to insert a single row, so you should use

```
INSERT INTO temptable
   (task_name, duration)
VALUES (NEW.task_name , NEW.duration);
```

Comment: What if I have to perform a `join`? How can I avoid `select` in that? For eg: https://pastebin.com/kangQ5ex

Comment: @AviralSrivastava Please ask you own question about that, with a code sample as small as possible and a good description of what exactly you want to do.